# CoreData configurations

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Let's say that I have 20 entities in my model at all. I need to separate these entities into 2 real storages. According to docs I have to setup two different(besides `Default`) configurations and use them later like:

```
self.persistentStore = try self.storeCoordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: configurationName, at: url, options: nil)
```

No errors, warnings or something suspicious until I check the underlying sqlite storage — real database has *all* 20 entities! What I'm doing wrong? or what I misunderstand?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do both files exist or just one?

Comment: @TomHarrington, both have identical structure.